# SVG - animate x position of pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I've created a "wavy" edge using svg, repeated horizontally using the `<pattern>` tag.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/FEFLq/3/

I need to animate the waves from left to right, i've noticed changing the x attribute on the  element does this. But i can't select it using jQuery.

Any ideas?

n.b - i'm intending to color transform the "wavy" svg pattern, hence using svg and not a background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think jQuery only animates CSS properties by default. The `x` on `pattern` is an attribute, so you'll have to provide a custom setter function for it. jQuery shouldn't have a problem selecting the `pattern` element (as long as the svg is inline in the html document).

Alternatively you could consider using another library, e.g [d3.js](http://d3js.org).